# What can be said about moments of probability distribution if it satisifies hemholtz equation?

Tags: pr.probability, fourier-analysis, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, interpolation

From physical considerations I have observed, that probability density in region of interest satisfies 
$$
\Delta u(x) + \phi(x)u(x) = f(x),
$$
where $\phi(x)$ and $f(x)$ are both given functions and $u$ negligible outside of this region.
What can be said about moments of $u$? Specifically I'm interested in variation. Can I compute it faster that solving the equation above (with appropriate boundary conditions) and doing integrations later? I've been thinking about using characteristic function, i.e. applying Fourier transform, but  I've got something like
$$
F[u](t) = \frac{F[\phi u](t) - F[f](t)}{t^2}.
$$
Surprisingly $F[u](0)$ don't depend on $f$ if $f$ is a constant, while from physical standpoint it obviously should.

So, I have two questions: 
1) do I write characteristic function of probability density function $u$ correctly?
2) is there a simple way of finding $\operatorname {Var} (x)$ under assumption $u$ is solution of above-mentioned Helmholtz equation?

Comment: the Fourier transform of a constant $f$ is a delta function $f\delta(t)$, why do you conclude $f$ does not contribute for $t=0$?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the``region of interest''? Depending on $\phi$, the equation that you wrote  may have multiple solutions $u$.

Comment: on a different note, do you really mean ${\rm Var}\,(u)$ or is it ${\rm Var}\,(x)$ that you are seeking (so the integral $\int x^2 u(x) dx$)? -- I have no idea what you mean by ${\rm Var}\, (u)$....

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I use L'Hôpital's rule to find the limit and $\delta'(t) / 2t = 0$, because $\delta(t) t^2 = 0$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu The region of interest is usually big enough box (I used 1 dimensional example, while in fact I have this equation in $k$ dimensions). 
Boundary conditions are of Dirichlet type with small or zero values on all sides of box and $\phi$ is something I measure in enough number of points to make the equation solvable. From the physics of the problem, I think everything should be fine with uniqueness and existence of solution.

Comment: The ssumption that $ f $ is constant contradicts the assumption that $ u $ decays rapidly

Comment: @Bananach yes, you are right, thank you.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure there is no easier way to get the mean than to compute  the solution and then take its mean. However,  the thus obtained estimates may have better convergence rates than the solution itself,  depending on your discretion method.

Comment: @Bananach do you thing the same applies to variance? And what discretization method you think would do better?